# Deglazing pan with textured coating

Tags: equipment, frying-pan, deglazing

I saw some frying pans in the store with unfamiliar nonstick coatings called Megastone, and Granite something. Both of those surfaces are not smooth but are flecked with slightly raised specks, supposedly contributing to their properties. Now suppose I sear something in those pans, building a fond, and deglaze. One would suppose the fond should come off the nonstick easily, but I'd still need to push it around a bit to dissolve in the deglazing liquid. Will the bumpiness not hinder that? Is the handling stable long term?